# Victory.js get x,y data from hovered line point

Tags: victory-charts, victory-native

How can I get the x,y data of a point on hover in a victory line component?

I tried this:

```js
            <VictoryLine
              data={data}
              style={{ data: { stroke: Colors.green } }}
              events={[
                {
                  target: 'parent',
                  eventHandlers: {
                    onMouseOver: () => {
                      return [
                        {
                          target: 'data',
                          mutation: (props) => {
                            // props.data returns the values of all data points
                          },
                        },
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                },
              ]}
            />
```

Is there a possible way to do this in victory.js?

Answer (score 0):

**Separating the different components of a victory chart**

| No | Component | Purpose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VictoryChart | It is a wrapper components, it is good to use to share events |
| 2 | VictoryVoronoiContainer | It is useful for hover interactions like tooltip |
| 3 | VictoryTooltip | It is used for tooltip |
| 4 | VictoryAxis | It is used for the axis, tickLabels |
| 5 | VictoryLine | It is used for single line path |

**Dummy Data**

```
const data = [
  {
    each: "2022-12-19",
    total: 1
  },
  {
    each: "2022-12-20",
    total: 15
  },
  {
    each: "2022-12-21",
    total: 8
  },
  {
    each: "2022-12-22",
    total: 21
  },
  {
    each: "2022-12-23",
    total: 3
  }
];
```

**Code**

```
<VictoryChart
  domainPadding={20}
  height={300}
  containerComponent={
    <VictoryVoronoiContainer
      voronoiDimension="x"
      labels={({ datum }) =>
        `x: ${datum.each}, y: ${datum.total}`
      }
      labelComponent={
        <VictoryTooltip
          cornerRadius={0}
          flyoutStyle={{
            fill: "white",
            stroke: "blue"
          }}
        />
      }
    />
  }
>
  <VictoryLine
    width={10}
    data={data}
    style={{
      labels: {
        fill: "blue"
      },
      data: {
        stroke: "blue",
        strokeWidth: 4
      }
    }}
    labels={({ datum }) => datum.y}
    x={"each"}
    y={"total"}
    height={250}
  />
  <VictoryAxis
    tickFormat={(x) => x}
    style={{
      tickLabels: { fill: "transparent" },
      axis: { stroke: "transparent" },
      ticks: { stroke: "transparent" }
    }}
  />
  <VictoryAxis
    dependentAxis
    style={{
      tickLabels: { fill: "transparent" },
      axis: { stroke: "transparent" },
      ticks: { stroke: "transparent" }
    }}
  />
</VictoryChart>
```

[image: Edit Victory Line Label]

**Explanation**

- To get the x,y data on a point, you need a tooltip
- Use the `VictoryChart` and add `VictoryVoronoiContainer`

`VictoryVoronoiContainer`

| No | Props | What it does |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | label | To show the label data from your data point |
| 2 | labelComponent | Use `VictoryTooltip` to gain more control |

`VictoryTooltip`

| No | Props | What it does |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | flyoutStyle | Use stroke to change border color, fill -> background color |

`VictoryAxis`
This is just used to change the color of the axis and the ticks.

Hopefully this was clear.
This method works very well for tooltip situations

`events` can be used to show tooltip. However this only works victory bars and some others but not victory line.